# How to combine repeated header columns for multi-index pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-manipulation

Current dataframe:

```
    a     a    b     b      c 
    k     l    m     n      o
a   1     2    9     1      4
b   2     3    9     2      4
c   3     8    7     8      3
d   8     8    9     0      0
```

desired dataframe:

```
       a          b         c 
    k     l    m     n      o
a   1     2    9     1      4
b   2     3    9     2      4
c   3     8    7     8      3
d   8     8    9     0      0
```

Its a multi index data frame, want to create a dynamic method to group the same headers into one for the columns where its repeated.

Comment: So there is `MultiIndex` and DataFrames looks like in first paragraph? What is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: Because by default `MultiIndex` grouping repeated first levels, only not aligned in center

Answer (score 1):

The two dataframes are exactly the same. If you want to change the style of the display you can do the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 9, 1, 4],
                           [2, 3, 9, 2, 4],
                           [3, 8, 7, 8, 3],
                           [8, 8, 9, 0, 0]]),
                 columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([list('aabbc'), list('klmno')]),
                 index =list('abcd')
                 )
```

default print style:

```
>>> print(df)

   a     b     c
   k  l  m  n  o
a  1  2  9  1  4
b  2  3  9  2  4
c  3  8  7  8  3
d  8  8  9  0  0
```

Alternative style:

```
>>> with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
...     print (df)

   a  a  b  b  c
   k  l  m  n  o
a  1  2  9  1  4
b  2  3  9  2  4
c  3  8  7  8  3
d  8  8  9  0  0
```